# DISTINCT values from multiple columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the following assignment:

> Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has the same last name and billing address as another customer. Sort the result set by last name then first name.

I have tried doing it with the `DISTINCT` keyword but that does not serve my purpose.

For some reason every time I use `GROUP BY` I get the following error:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, BillingAddressID
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY LastName;
```

> Column 'Customers.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I tried UNION with the following error:

```
SELECT LastName FROM Customers

UNION 

SELECT BillingAddressID FROM Customers
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Sherwood' to data type int.

Can someone just point me in the right direction?

This is a sample of the data set that I am working on

```
firstname   lastname    billingaddressid  
Allan       Sherwood        2  
Barry       Zimmer          3  
Christine   Brown           4  
David       Goldstein       6  
Erin        Sherwood        7  
Frank Lee   Wilson          8  
Gary        Brown           4  
Heather     Esway           12
```

So, the query should remove the duplicate entries..of the lastname

Comment: Show us some sample data and desired output.

Comment: firstname lastname billingaddressid   
Allan  Sherwood  2
Barry Zimmer   3
Christine Brown   4
David Goldstein          6
Erin  Sherwood  7
Frank LeeWilson   8
Gary  Brown   10
Heather Esway   12

Comment: What are you expecting as output? also, SQLServer or mySQL?

Comment: @DarkKnight SQLServer..It should return either Gary Brown or christine Brown from the above data set as they have the same last name ...doesnt matter which ...

Comment: The `GROUP BY` attempt works for me, but has the effect of only listing the first Person with each LastName.  All subsequent Customers' with a shared LastName are not listed.

Comment: `UNION' add's the entries from the second table to the first, but not the structure.  It would be useful if you were trying to merge two lists of Customers from different tables, for instance.  It does require that each field ("column") be of a matching type.

Comment: @JyotiOdrani : Try my answer.

Comment: In your full dataset, can 2 or more Customers have the same billingaddressid?

Comment: In your full dataset, can 2 or more Customers have the same billingaddressid?

Comment: @Toonice Yes 2 or more customers can have the same billing address id...

Comment: Thanks - I shall edit my answer accordingly.  Please note : The sample data you provided does not have any repeated billingaddressid's, and since you didn't detail your source table's structure, I misinterpreted this as likely meaning that billingaddressid was either the Primary Key or otherwise meant to be unique.  I shall update my sample dataset to compensate for this.  As a recommendation, in the future when asking a question detail your source table(s) structure(s)  and include that a sample dataset that will enable us to test each point of concern.

Comment: Also, sorry about the delay - I got called away.

Comment: Edited (again) answer posted.  Please feel free to conatct me if you have any questions.

Comment: Why have you used tags for My-SQL and SQL-Server?

Comment: @toonice this being the first time that I have asked a question and I am making many mistakes ...but thanks for the answer and more thanks for the explanation that you have provided..I always tried to avoid inner join as I thought that it was confusing...but then it is much more clear now..and I think i will definitely be coming back for more help..:))

Comment: No worries - actually quite a good first try.  And don't worry about the "mistakes" - nobody expects perfection, especially not on your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
SELECT FirstName,
       Customers.LastName,
       Customers.billingAddressID
FROM Customers INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT LastName,
              billingAddressID
       FROM Customers
       GROUP BY LastName,
                billingAddressID
       HAVING COUNT( LastName ) >= 2 ) lastNameQuery
  ON Customers.LastName = lastNameQuery.LastName AND
     Customers.billingAddressID = lastNameQuery.billingAddressID
ORDER BY Customers.LastName,
         FirstName;
```

I tested this against a database created using the following script...

```
CREATE DATABASE Cust;

USE Cust;

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    fldID               INT              NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName           VARCHAR( 50 )    NOT NULL,
    lastName            VARCHAR( 50 ),
    billingAddressID    INT              NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( fldID )
);
```

I entered the Questioner's sample data using -

```
INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Allan",
    lastName         = "Sherwood",
    billingAddressID = 2;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Barry",
    lastName         = "Zimmer",
    billingAddressID = 3;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Christine",
    lastName         = "Brown",
    billingAddressID = 4;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "David",
    lastName         = "Goldstein",
    billingAddressID = 6;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Erin",
    lastName         = "Sherwood",
    billingAddressID = 7;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Frank Lee",
    lastName         = "Wilson",
    billingAddressID = 8;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Gary",
    lastName         = "Brown",
    billingAddressID = 10;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Heather",
    lastName         = "Esway",
    billingAddressID = 12;
```

I also added the following to ensure a repeat of BOTH lastName AND billingAddressID...

```
INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Don",
    lastName         = "Sherwood",
    billingAddressID = 22;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "Timmy",
    lastName         = "Sherwood",
    billingAddressID = 22;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "James",
    lastName         = "Brown",
    billingAddressID = 22;

INSERT INTO Customers
SET firstName        = "James",
    lastName         = "Esway",
    billingAddressID = 22;
```

The question being asked of our Questioner, and I assume the question that the Questioner is seeking help with, was -

```
Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has the same last name and billing address as another customer. Sort the result set by last name then first name.
```

My interpretation of this was we should return records for EACH Customer meeting the criteria of having a particular combination BOTH a Last Name AND a BillingAddressID shared with AT LEAST one other Customer, and that the list of returned records should be sorted by Last Name and subsorted on First Name.

The core of my answer is the segment -

```
SELECT LastName,
       billingAddressID
FROM Customers
```

Which selects just the two conditional fields from Customers.

To this I added -

```
GROUP BY LastName,
         billingAddressID
```

This will refine the core segments results into a list of each unique combination of the two conditional fields.

I then restricted this list to those unique combinations that occur at least twice by adding -

```
HAVING COUNT( LastName ) >= 2
```

I then gave the resulting query an Alias of `lastNameQuery`.

I then joined lastNameQuery with Customers on both conditional fields to restrict our list of Customers to those who had a shared pair of conditional values using -

```
     Customers INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT LastName,
              billingAddressID
       FROM Customers
       GROUP BY LastName,
                billingAddressID
       HAVING COUNT( LastName ) >= 2 ) lastNameQuery
  ON Customers.LastName = lastNameQuery.LastName AND
     Customers.billingAddressID = lastNameQuery.billingAddressID
```

From this I selected the desired fields using -

```
SELECT FirstName,
       Customers.LastName,
       Customers.billingAddressID
FROM
```

Using `Customers.` was necessitated by the need to clarify references to field names that occur in both `Customers` and `lastNameQuery`.  Without this clarification MySQL is unable to determine which fields it should use.

This list was sorted into the specified order by adding -

```
ORDER BY Customers.LastName,
         FirstName;
```

The results I got from testing my complete statement were -

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| FirstName | LastName | billingAddressID |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| Gary      | Brown    |               10 |
| Tom       | Brown    |               10 |
| Don       | Sherwood |               22 |
| Timmy     | Sherwood |               22 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
```

These are the only Customers in my expanded sample dataset to have a shared combination of values in the conditional fields.

Comment: It says incorrect syntax near Sort... and if my understanding of the question is right i think that i need to get distinct lastnames and billingaddresses

Comment: still returns nothing

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying..and thanks a lot for explaining this so well..I know that I didnt post the question properly but this is my first time and I am still making mistakes..

Comment: No worries.  I'm still new to alot of this myself.  And you posted the question quite well.  I liked how you quoted the question you had been given - this provided us with the same point of reference you were using and helped us to make more clear interpretations of the rest of your question.  A clear statement of what you are trying to chieve is very important.  Your sample data set was also good, just not complete enough to test against quite all of the possibilities.  Don't worry too much about that - designing a good set of test data can be very challenging, regardless of experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89cb3c/1)

```
   SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LASTNAME ORDER BY FIRSTNAME) AS RN
    FROM YOURTABLE
    )T
    WHERE RN=2
```

If you want to return all unique records.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LASTNAME ORDER BY FIRSTNAME) AS RN
    FROM YOURTABLE
    )T
    WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 occurrences of a LastName?

Comment: @toonice :  RowNumber 2 is still generated in that case.

Comment: The Question given to Jyoti Odrani was "Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for EACH customer that has the same last name and billing address as another customer" (emphasis added).  Your answer eliminates Christine Brown, who should also be returned as per the Question, as well as any other Brown's that may occur in a full dataset.  Ditto for any other shared names.

Comment: @DarkKnight  Yes its working..I am still Checking it one or two other sets of data to be sure..I just added BillingAddressID in the partition by clause...Thanks a lot...

Comment: This last comment makes no sense - does it mean that we should remove all entries with a duplicate name or just the duplicate entries?  And which are the "duplicate entries"?  It's a moot point, since the Question that was presented to Jyoti Odrani was more in line with my above comment.